# OkHttp POST sending invalid format to Pocketbase

Tags: java, http, okhttp, pocketbase

I'm trying to send a `POST` request via OkHttp to my local Pocketbase server, but it's not working.

In Pocketbase, I have a collection called `servers`. I have a field called `guild_id` which is set to the `Number` type. For now, the access is admin-only. I'm using OkHttp with Java to try to add a new record. Here is the code:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
final String url = "http://localhost:8090/api/collections/servers/records";
final long serverId = 123L;
final String token = System.getenv("token");

RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("guild_id", String.valueOf(serverId))
        .build();

Request r = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .post(body)
        .build();

try (Response resp = client.newCall(r).execute()) {
    if (!resp.isSuccessful()) {
        System.err.println("Error posting to pocketbase: " + resp.body().string());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Request successful. Response: " + resp.body().string());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run this code, it always gives the same error:

```
Error posting to pocketbase: {"code":400,"message":"Failed to load the submitted data due to invalid formatting.","data":{}}
```

I tried to send the same request via Postman, and ***it worked***. I'm really not sure what's up, I suspect it might be the way Java and/or OkHttp handles requests? Anyway, does anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: If it works with Postman and not with your implementation I suggest you intercept the http traffic and take a look at the difference. A tool like httptoolkit, Wireshark or wiremock could help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (thanks to Thomas W's comment). Courtesy of Wireshark, I found out that OkHttp was sending an `application/json` content type instead of `multipart/form-data`.

To fix this, I used `MultipartBody.Builder` instead of `FormBody.Builder` and specified the type like this:

```java
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("guild_id", String.valueOf(serverId))
        .build();
```

---

*If you're curious...*

Here is OkHttp's old request:
[image: Image showing OkHttp's request as application/json]

vs Postman's:
[image: Image showing Postman's request as multipart/form-data]